# Multilingual User Interface (MUI) not works with SiteTemplates

Tags: 2010, content-type, site-template, spweb, multilingual

I've created a CType and create columns namings for multiple languages by changing the current language and set the corresponding naming. Then I create a Subsite (same language based) using those same CTypes. So far so good, everythings works as expected.

I save that subsite as a **SiteTemplate**, and then, creating anothers **subsites from that template the MUI translations don't work no more** (Not only the content typed fields but all other list titles namings). I try to **export** the translations from the template **and import them is the created subsite, but still not working.**

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Since its not an answer ill add a comment. If I remember correctly you can use Content and Structure to just copy the subsite, it will not reset the MUI translations. But again, not that viable always :)

Comment: No, not for my requirements. However, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. So I created WebProvisioned event receiver to translate all new webs in the server-side code.